# Can you interpolate my polynomials if I give you some randomized values

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, interpolation

Scenario (1)

We define the polynomial ring $R[x]$ consist of all polynomial with coefficients from $\mathbb Z_p$, where $p$ is a prime number. Let $P_i$ be a polynomial such that $P_i \in R[x]$. We evaluate $P_1$ at many  $X= (x_1,...,x_n)$ to obtain $Y^{(1)}=(y_1,...,y_n)$, where $n$ can we very large and far more greater than $d+1$, where $d$ is the polynomial degree. We multiply each element in $Y^{(1)}$ by the distinct value chosen uniformly at random from $\mathbb Z_p$, and we denote the result by $Y'^{(1)}=(y_1 \times r_1,...,y_n \times r_n)$, where $r_i$ are random value picked uniformly from $\mathbb Z_p$. The roots of this polynomial matter to us, therefore if one can recover the original polynomial, $P_1$, or by any means he recovers the root(s) (or any knowledge of the roots) our protocol is broken. We publish the $X= (x_1,...,x_n)$ and $Y'^{(1)}$, so anybody can access them (including those who wants to try to figure out the original polynomial and its roots).

Questions 1:

### - Given $X$ and  $Y'^{(1)}$'s, can anybody deduce any information  about the original polynomial (e.g. the roots of the polynomial or the degree of the polynomial, etc)?

Scenario (2)

We have many (millions) of polynomials  $P_i$ and we evaluate all of them at the same $X= (x_1,...,x_n)$, to obtain $Y^{(1)},..., Y^{(n)}$. Similar to the scenario (1), we multiply each element in $Y^{(i)}$ by a distinct uniformly at random value $r_i$ (i.e. note all $r_i$'s are random for all elements in all  $Y_i$'s) to obtain $Y'^{(1)},..., Y'^{(n)}$.

Questions 2:

- Given $X$ and  all $Y'^{(i)}$, can anybody deduce any information  about the original polynomial (e.g. the root(s) or the degree of these polynomials)?

Remark: The main reason that the scenario(2) is different than (1) is that the $Y'^{(i)}$'s are somehow linked to each other, as all are the result of evaluation of different polynomials at the same $X$ values. So this may give enough advantage to whoever wants to figure out some information about the original polynomials.

Question 3: If we evaluate a polynomial on some $X$'s to obtain some $Y$ values, Why multiplying $Y$'s by distinct random values is not equal to multiplying the original polynomial by another polynomial?

Many thanks

Comment: Is this for some kind of cryptography ?

Comment: @TheGame Maybe. Indeed it is to avoid using cryptography.

Comment: A polynomial of degree $d$ is fully determined by $d-1$ points. However, there exists an __infinity__ of polynomials that go through $d$ fixed points, all having if you want different roots and coefficients. Hence, if the degree is unknown, I highly doubt once can find the roots.

Comment: @TheGame Can I ask you why you said "infinity of polynomials that go ..". More Precisely, what made you say that?

Comment: Take, for instance, Lagrange interpolation polynomials of degree $d+2$. They are determined by $d+1$ points, hence if you take the set of all those that go through the $d$ first points  + any other, it makes an infinity of different polynomials. There are infinitely many more, as that can be applied for all degrees $>d+1$ (PS : I have to go, don't except me to answer any new comment for ~3 hours)